# paring JSON data as string

Tags: java, android, json

i try to parse the json file as a string to use it to display this date in listview i tried like the course's video but i have this error but in video it works

```
 public class QueryUtils {

    private QueryUtils(){
    }
    private final static String QUERY_UTILS_URL = "{  \"kind\": \"books#volumes\",  \"totalItems\": 392,  \"items\": [    {      \"kind\": \"books#volume\",      \"id\": \"qKFDDAAAQBAJ\",      \"etag\": \"REv5wZ4Dkek\",      \"selfLink\": \"https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/qKFDDAAAQBAJ\",      \"volumeInfo\": {        \"title\": \"Android\",        \"authors\": [          \"P.K. Dixit\"        ],        \"publisher\": \"Vikas Publishing House\",        \"publishedDate\": \"2014\",        \"description\": \"Android is a movement that has transferred data from laptop to hand-held devices like mobiles. Though there are alternate technologies that compete with Android, but it is the front runner in mobile technology by a long distance. Good knowledge in basic Java will help you to understand and develop Android technology and apps. Many universities in India and across the world are now teaching Android in their syllabus, which shows the importance of this subject. This book can be read by anyone who knows Java and XML concepts. It includes a lot of diagrams along with explanations to facilitate better understanding by students. This book aptly concludes with a project that uses Android, which will greatly benefit students in learning the practical aspects of Android. Key Features • Instructions in designing different Android user interfaces • Thorough explanations of all activities • JSON • Android-based project to aid practical understanding\",        \"industryIdentifiers\": [          {            \"type\": \"ISBN_13\",            \"identifier\": \"9789325977884\"          },          {            \"type\": \"ISBN_10\",            \"identifier\": \"9325977885\"          }        ],        \"readingModes\": {          \"text\": false,          \"image\": true        },        \"pageCount\": 372,        \"printType\": \"BOOK\",        \"categories\": [          \"Computers\"        ],        \"averageRating\": 3,        \"ratingsCount\": 1,        \"maturityRating\": \"NOT_MATURE\",        \"allowAnonLogging\": true,        \"contentVersion\": \"preview-1.0.0\",        \"panelizationSummary\": {          \"containsEpubBubbles\": false,          \"containsImageBubbles\": false        },        \"imageLinks\": {          \"smallThumbnail\": \"http://books.google.com/books/content?id=qKFDDAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=5&edge=curl&source=gbs_api\",          \"thumbnail\": \"http://books.google.com/books/content?id=qKFDDAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&source=gbs_api\"        },        \"language\": \"en\",        \"previewLink\": \"http://books.google.com.eg/books?id=qKFDDAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=android&hl=&cd=1&source=gbs_api\",        \"infoLink\": \"https://play.google.com/store/books/details?id=qKFDDAAAQBAJ&source=gbs_api\",        \"canonicalVolumeLink\": \"https://play.google.com/store/books/details?id=qKFDDAAAQBAJ\"      },      \"saleInfo\": {        \"country\": \"EG\",        \"saleability\": \"FOR_SALE\",        \"isEbook\": true,        \"listPrice\": {          \"amount\": 236.25,          \"currencyCode\": \"EGP\"        },        \"retailPrice\": {          \"amount\": 236.25,          \"currencyCode\": \"EGP\"        },        \"buyLink\": \"https://play.google.com/store/books/details?id=qKFDDAAAQBAJ&rdid=book-qKFDDAAAQBAJ&rdot=1&source=gbs_api\",        \"offers\": [          {            \"finskyOfferType\": 1,            \"listPrice\": {              \"amountInMicros\": 236250000,              \"currencyCode\": \"EGP\"            },            \"retailPrice\": {              \"amountInMicros\": 236250000,              \"currencyCode\": \"EGP\"            }          }        ]      },      \"accessInfo\": {        \"country\": \"EG\",        \"viewability\": \"PARTIAL\",        \"embeddable\": true,        \"publicDomain\": false,        \"textToSpeechPermission\": \"ALLOWED\",        \"epub\": {          \"isAvailable\": false        },        \"pdf\": {          \"isAvailable\": true,          \"acsTokenLink\": \"http://books.google.com.eg/books/download/Android-sample-pdf.acsm?id=qKFDDAAAQBAJ&format=pdf&output=acs4_fulfillment_token&dl_type=sample&source=gbs_api\"        },        \"webReaderLink\": \"http://play.google.com/books/reader?id=qKFDDAAAQBAJ&hl=&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_api\",        \"accessViewStatus\": \"SAMPLE\",        \"quoteSharingAllowed\": false      },      \"searchInfo\": {        \"textSnippet\": \"Many universities in India and across the world are now teaching Android in their syllabus, which shows the importance of this subject. This book can be read by anyone who knows Java and XML concepts.\"}}]}";

    public static ArrayList<CustomBookModel> bookModels (){
        ArrayList<CustomBookModel> bookModelArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        try{
            JSONObject books = new JSONObject(QUERY_UTILS_URL);
            JSONArray booksArray = new JSONArray("items");
            for (int i = 0 ;i < booksArray.length() ;i++ ){
                JSONObject currentBook =booksArray.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONObject infoVolumes = currentBook.getJSONObject("volumeInfo");
                String title = infoVolumes.getString("title");
                String author = infoVolumes.getString("authors");

                CustomBookModel book = new CustomBookModel(title ,author);
                bookModelArrayList.add(book);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
           Log.e("QueryUtils" , "problem parsing ...." , e);
        }
        return bookModelArrayList;
    }}
```

but i have this error in logcat

```
 10-26 11:47:34.575 10591-10591/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
    10-26 11:47:34.575 10591-10591/? I/art: VMHOOK: rlim_cur : 0 pid:10591
    10-26 11:47:34.653 10591-10591/com.example.bookslist W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.bookslist-1/lib/arm
    10-26 11:47:34.703 10591-10591/com.example.bookslist W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
    10-26 11:47:34.771 10591-10591/com.example.bookslist I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2>
    10-26 11:47:34.772 10591-10591/com.example.bookslist I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2>
    10-26 11:47:34.911 10591-10591/com.example.bookslist E/QueryUtils: problem parsing ....
        org.json.JSONException: Value items of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
            at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
            at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:96)
            at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:108)
            at com.example.bookslist.QueryUtils.bookModels(QueryUtils.java:21)
            at com.example.bookslist.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6248)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1125)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2437)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2544)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:150)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1394)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5845)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
    10-26 11:47:35.029 10591-10605/com.example.bookslist I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: Nondeterministic_AU_msm8974_LA.BF.1.1.3__release_AU (I3fa967cfef)
        OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.28.00.02
        Build Date: 09/29/15 Tue
        Local Branch: mybranch14683032
        Remote Branch: quic/master
        Local Patches: NONE
        Reconstruct Branch: NOTHING
```

and i still learning it but the course's video was did it and it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
public static ArrayList<CustomBookModel> bookModels (){
    ArrayList<CustomBookModel> bookModelArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    try{
        JSONObject books = new JSONObject(QUERY_UTILS_URL);
        JSONArray booksArray = books.getJSONArray("items");
        for (int i = 0 ;i < booksArray.length() ;i++ ){
            JSONObject currentBook =booksArray.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONObject infoVolumes = currentBook.getJSONObject("volumeInfo");
            String title = infoVolumes.getString("title");
            String author = infoVolumes.getString("authors");

            CustomBookModel book = new CustomBookModel(title ,author);
            bookModelArrayList.add(book);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
       Log.e("QueryUtils" , "problem parsing ...." , e);
    }
    return bookModelArrayList;
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

> `JSONArray booksArray = new JSONArray("items");`

This makes a new, empty json array object, and then creates a new variable named `booksArray`, and then sets that variable to be a reference to this newly created object, which is an empty array.

This is not how you fetch that `items` array in the JSONObject you have. You're looking for something like `books.get("items")`.

More generally, that json library is deplorably bad; use something like GSON or Jackson instead.

Comment: i still learning how to parse json data and display it in list but in course's video do like this and worked

Comment: Then you misunderstood the course video; they _added_ a bunch of stuff to that array. This code does not work, as you yourself are observing.